# Inclusion Exclusion Principle Question

Tags: combinatorics

A merchant have 3 kinds of coins in his pocket: r of copper, s of aluminum and t of gold.
He randomly take out 3 coins from his pocket.
how much combinations there are in which he will pull 3 coins made of the same material.

Taking 3 coins from the pocket is ${r+s+t \choose 3}$, so due to the Inclusion Exclusion Principle we can conclude (because there is no interaction between the coins) that  ${r \choose 3}+{s \choose 3}+{t \choose 3}$
but do not we need to taking into account the whole (r+s+t)?

Answer (score 3):

No.  You do not need to consider everything in the bag, only that from which you are selecting, in each case.

There are ${r \choose 3}$ ways to select $3$ copper coins from $r$ distinct copper coins.  It does not matter what else is in the bag if you are only selecting from among the copper coins.

Likewise for aluminium and gold, for $s \choose 3$ and $t \choose 3$ combinations each, respectively.

$$\text{For a total of }{r\choose 3}+{s\choose 3}+{t\choose 3} \text{ combinations} \\ = \frac{r!}{3!\;(r-3)!}+\frac{s!}{3!\;(s-3)!}+\frac{t!}{3!\;(t-3)!}$$